# How do I iterate explicitly over batches in TensorFlow dataset?

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow2.0

I have a Computer Vision application that analyzes very large (30k x 40x) images by breaking them into tiles; this tiling process produces a TensorFlow TFRecord file with one TFRecord per tile, potentially a large number like 5000.   What I would like to explicitly iterate over all the TFRecord in batches, and for each bunch, I want to use a Deep Learning model to produce a segmentation map for each tile.  So I would have something like:

```
    for input_tiles_tensor in break_into_batches( TFRecord_file, batch_size ):
        output_tiles_tensor is model.predict( input_tiles_tensors )
        ...use output_tile_tensor to generate output, written to file...
```

The part I need help with is `break_into_batches`   Suggestions welcome!

-------------------------------- ADDITION ---------------------------------------

I think I see an approach, BUT...   Here's the approach:

```
AUTO = tf.data.experimental.AUTOTUNE
image_feature = {
    'image': tf.io.FixedLenFeature([], tf.string),
}
def _parse_image(example_proto):
    example = tf.io.parse_single_example(example_proto, image_feature, name = "parse_example")
    dim_with_overlap = P[ 'DIM' ] + 2 * P[ 'PIXEL_OVERLAP' ]
    image = tf.reshape( tf.io.decode_raw(example['image'],out_type=np.dtype('uint8')), 
                        (dim_with_overlap, dim_with_overlap, 3))
    return image


dataset = tf.data.TFRecordDataset( "../input/blortzk-hubmap-test-overlapping-tiled-images/test/26dc41664-6068.tfrec",
                                   compression_type = "GZIP" )
dataset = dataset.batch( 77 )
dataset = dataset.prefetch(AUTO)
dataset = dataset.map(_parse_image)

iterator = iter( dataset )
batch = iterator.get_next()
print( "type( batch )", type( batch ), "batch.shape", batch.shape, file = sys.stderr )
```

The BUT is that this gives an error in the `dataset.map` statement:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-25-67a2e02c344d> in <module>
     15 dataset = dataset.batch( 77 )
     16 dataset = dataset.prefetch(AUTO)
---> 17 dataset = dataset.map(_parse_image)
     18 
     19 iterator = iter( dataset )

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/data/ops/dataset_ops.py in map(self, map_func, num_parallel_calls, deterministic)
   1693     """
   1694     if num_parallel_calls is None:
-> 1695       return MapDataset(self, map_func, preserve_cardinality=True)
   1696     else:
   1697       return ParallelMapDataset(

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/data/ops/dataset_ops.py in __init__(self, input_dataset, map_func, use_inter_op_parallelism, preserve_cardinality, use_legacy_function)
   4043         self._transformation_name(),
   4044         dataset=input_dataset,
-> 4045         use_legacy_function=use_legacy_function)
   4046     variant_tensor = gen_dataset_ops.map_dataset(
   4047         input_dataset._variant_tensor,  # pylint: disable=protected-access

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/data/ops/dataset_ops.py in __init__(self, func, transformation_name, dataset, input_classes, input_shapes, input_types, input_structure, add_to_graph, use_legacy_function, defun_kwargs)
   3369       with tracking.resource_tracker_scope(resource_tracker):
   3370         # TODO(b/141462134): Switch to using garbage collection.
-> 3371         self._function = wrapper_fn.get_concrete_function()
   3372         if add_to_graph:
   3373           self._function.add_to_graph(ops.get_default_graph())

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/function.py in get_concrete_function(self, *args, **kwargs)
   2937     """
   2938     graph_function = self._get_concrete_function_garbage_collected(
-> 2939         *args, **kwargs)
   2940     graph_function._garbage_collector.release()  # pylint: disable=protected-access
   2941     return graph_function

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/function.py in _get_concrete_function_garbage_collected(self, *args, **kwargs)
   2904       args, kwargs = None, None
   2905     with self._lock:
-> 2906       graph_function, args, kwargs = self._maybe_define_function(args, kwargs)
   2907       seen_names = set()
   2908       captured = object_identity.ObjectIdentitySet(

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/function.py in _maybe_define_function(self, args, kwargs)
   3211 
   3212       self._function_cache.missed.add(call_context_key)
-> 3213       graph_function = self._create_graph_function(args, kwargs)
   3214       self._function_cache.primary[cache_key] = graph_function
   3215       return graph_function, args, kwargs

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/function.py in _create_graph_function(self, args, kwargs, override_flat_arg_shapes)
   3073             arg_names=arg_names,
   3074             override_flat_arg_shapes=override_flat_arg_shapes,
-> 3075             capture_by_value=self._capture_by_value),
   3076         self._function_attributes,
   3077         function_spec=self.function_spec,

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/func_graph.py in func_graph_from_py_func(name, python_func, args, kwargs, signature, func_graph, autograph, autograph_options, add_control_dependencies, arg_names, op_return_value, collections, capture_by_value, override_flat_arg_shapes)
    984         _, original_func = tf_decorator.unwrap(python_func)
    985 
--> 986       func_outputs = python_func(*func_args, **func_kwargs)
    987 
    988       # invariant: `func_outputs` contains only Tensors, CompositeTensors,

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/data/ops/dataset_ops.py in wrapper_fn(*args)
   3362           attributes=defun_kwargs)
   3363       def wrapper_fn(*args):  # pylint: disable=missing-docstring
-> 3364         ret = _wrapper_helper(*args)
   3365         ret = structure.to_tensor_list(self._output_structure, ret)
   3366         return [ops.convert_to_tensor(t) for t in ret]

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/data/ops/dataset_ops.py in _wrapper_helper(*args)
   3297         nested_args = (nested_args,)
   3298 
-> 3299       ret = autograph.tf_convert(func, ag_ctx)(*nested_args)
   3300       # If `func` returns a list of tensors, `nest.flatten()` and
   3301       # `ops.convert_to_tensor()` would conspire to attempt to stack

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/autograph/impl/api.py in wrapper(*args, **kwargs)
    256       except Exception as e:  # pylint:disable=broad-except
    257         if hasattr(e, 'ag_error_metadata'):
--> 258           raise e.ag_error_metadata.to_exception(e)
    259         else:
    260           raise

ValueError: in user code:

    <ipython-input-25-67a2e02c344d>:6 _parse_image  *
        example = tf.io.parse_single_example(example_proto, image_feature, name = "parse_example")
    /opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/util/dispatch.py:201 wrapper  **
        return target(*args, **kwargs)
    /opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/parsing_ops.py:451 parse_single_example_v2
        serialized = _assert_scalar(serialized, "serialized")
    /opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/parsing_ops.py:1058 _assert_scalar
        raise ValueError("Input %s must be a scalar" % name)

    ValueError: Input serialized must be a scalar
```

I'm able to use this TFRecord file in other settings, so I guess my iteration mechanism is faulty.  Please help.